# static relocation about c

Tags: c, linker

Every machine code about text section in object file have address, it will from 0 to a number.

When the linker links all object files, the address about instruction will change.

I can't see if the linker will read instruction about text section one by one in order to change every instruction address.

```
Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <_start>:

    0:  bf 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%edi
    5:  8b 04 bd 00 00 00 00    mov    0x0(,%edi,4),%eax
    c:  89 c3                   mov    %eax,%ebx
```

**by linked**

```
08048074 <_start>:

    8048074:    bf 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%edi
    8048079:    8b 04 bd a0 90 04 08    mov    0x80490a0(,%edi,4),%eax
    8048080:    89 c3                   mov    %eax,%ebx
```

just like 0 → 8048074 and so on.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but the process is described in the `-fpic` related section in [`man gcc`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc).

Comment: What's the actual question?

Comment: There exists no machine code until the linker has created it, so I don't understand what you mean. "read instruction about text section one by one" from where?

Comment: The linker just adds an offset before loading the image in memory. As you can see all the addresses after linking are shifted by an offset of `<_start>` address. This happens all while the program is loaded in memory so the linker do not have to go one by one changing all the address, it just loads the `<_start>` section at the base address and all other instructions follow.

Comment: Thank you ! I have got it.   The instruction about  '0:  bf 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%edi'   is use a disassembler.  The text section just like 
 400410 31ed4989 d15e4889 e24883e4 f0505449  1.I..^H..H...PTI
 400420 c7c0a005 400048c7 c1100540 0048c7c7  ....@.H....@.H..
 400430 f4044000 e8c7ffff fff49090 4883ec08  ..@.........H...; The virtual address is not exist.

Comment: Read the Wikipedia article about [Position-independent code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright so I'm assuming you're using some unix based system as this seems like the output of objdump command, yet what as much as I know this is relevant for both ELF and PE files.

so let's start, firstly when you use c you compile some models into object files and eventually link them together, as seen earlier. e.g:

- `m1.c` -> `m1.o`
- `m2.c` -> `m2.o`
- `main.c` + `m2.o` + `m1.o` -> `main.exe`

we have some c programs called `m1.c` / `m2.c` that defines some functions, which are called by main.c, eventually all are linked and compiled together into main.exe which is fully executable.

now, let's dive in and see what happened under the hood. firstly I'd like to start with a very important beginning, within the final executable, in our example (main.exe) all addresses **are FULLY RESOLVED VIRTUAL ADDRESSES** (this is not necessarily true because of some concept called PIE / PIC but for now let's not get into it )

hence within you're executable, function `foo` within `m1.o` would have some resolved address (e.g 0x400100), within main.exe when foo is called you'll see within the disassembly something such as

```
call 0x400100
```

now this is what conceptually happens, now let's get into what actually happens.
when fetching instructions, e.g `jmp` or `call` instruction some address is given as an operand and then your processor's instruction register is changed to the address given as operand, so your question is smart, should the linker go instruction by instruction, find which are in need to be changed and change it? well NO, the linker simply doesn't do that, it is much smarter than that.

firstly, when compiling, the compiler generates jumps and calls to inner modules ( for example `jmp` to some address that should already belong within `m1.o` in our example ) relative to current instruction executing. what does that mean?
let's say we have some if statement, that would be compiled to jumps to some addresses, the compiler is smart enough to use a relative jump operand and place the offset between commands, hence when linking the linker doesn't even have to change those, it's irrelevant to which address the code is loaded as the calls are relative to current instruction and the offset between commands of some object file stays static through the linking stage.

now here's where things get a little bit more complex, we've covered how the linker avoids changing addresses within `m1.o`, now what if `m2.o` calls functions defined in `m1.o` both are executables and there is no way on earth that the compiler can assume the offset between them as they both have no idea with how many other models they would be linked in, how is this solved? Symbol and Relocation tables are introduced.

- **Symbol Table** - A table containing all symbols within your model - a
  symbol is something that other models may need to recognize by name,
  such as functions and global variables.
- **Relocation Table** - A table containing all "occurrences" of the
  symbols within some model.

You've may heard of these before, but now I shall explain to you about these.
before getting into it, I need to warn that I'm more familiar with ELF format files but as much as I know is that conceptually PE files work the same way.

let's look at this example code

```
#include <stdio.h>
/** file: m1.c **/

extern void goo();

void foo()
{
  printf("I am foo()!\n");
  goo();
}
```

and

```
#include <stdio.h>
/** file: m2.c **/

void goo()
{
  printf("I am goo()!\n");
}
```

when compiling `m1.o` within the object file, there would be some table saying something like this

SYMBOLS: `foo`-> at offset X within file, `goo`-> UNDEFINED
RELOCATION: `goo`-> at offset Y within file,

now what this means is that the compiler generates a table that collects all the functions that the model uses and determines whether they are defined - it gives the offset that the function is defined within filed, and if it's not defined it would state it,

also it would state that within this model goo is being called at offset X and it needs to be relocated (We'll get to my point, It's the answer to your question!)

when linking into an executable, the linker takes all symbols of all object files, resolves some address within them, and then goes through each symbol table of each object file, looks and determines which symbols are yet undefined, then it goes through the relocation table and looks at which calls are made to symbols that were undefined, goes that place within the file, and simply re-writes the address that was called to the address resolved, so if before we had something such as this in `m1.o`

```
call 0x000000 ;undefined goo address
```

after symbol resolving, linker would probably have some entry on relocation table saying you need to relocate goo address on line X and we'll result in

```
call 0x400100 ;actual goo address
```

FYI, when having an undefined reference linker error it means that you have some undefined symbol within your symbol table and the linker can't resolve a matching function definition for it... also if I have not made myself clear, this works exactly the same for global and static variables, they are also considered to be symbols